# Yii2. Cannot combine different validation rules together

Tags: yii2

```
[['captcha'], 'captcha', 'required'],
```

If I do this, it says:

> Setting unknown property: yii\captcha\CaptchaValidator::0

But it works fine if I do following:

```
['captcha', 'captcha'],
['captcha', 'required'],
```

What do you think the problem is? Why can't I combine the rules?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because in Yii, rules are represented as an array like this:

```
['field1', 'validator1', 'valProp1'=>'valProp1Value', 'valProp2'=>'valProp2Value', ...]
```

so this array applies only to 1 validator but multiple fields and valProp1, valProp2 are inbuilt Validator Class properties. Some example would be:

```
['field1', 'email','skipOnEmpty'=>true]
```

which setups `yii\validators\EmailValidator` on a `field1` field and setups `skipOnEmpty` property of email validator to `true`

In order to combine rules, you need to to write in format where every rule is separate per validator, something like this:

```
['captcha','captcha'],
['captcha','required']
```

Comment: Thank you, that makes sense!